# My comment disappeared. Why?

Tags: support, comments

A comment of mine disappeared from under the post https://stackoverflow.com/a/22842159/715269.

Obviously, it was flagged and deleted. Can I know why?

Comment: Flagged as not constructive, deleted by a mod.

Comment: Which I agree with. You are saying things are not useful, but not offering anything constructive.

Comment: @Oded The post is incorrect. I have commented it. From which time critics on the post is forbidden?

Comment: @Oded From which time pointing to the error of the post is not constructive?

Comment: @Gangus - you have asked why the comments were deleted. I have explained what happened. Whether that was moderated correctly or not is not in the scope of your question and is not something I wish to further comment upon.

Comment: @Oded I understood that they were flagged and deleted. It is in my question here. I am asking WHY it was done. So, your comments were really not constructive. Don't you want to delete them?

Comment: The only person who can answer why they were flagged is the flagger. Comments are second class citizens of SE sites and you can always expect them to be removed - whatever they contained. A moderator will normally simply delete a flagged comment.

Comment: @Oded thank you. This is really a new and very unexpected info. What is the sense of moderator's participation if he "normally simply delete a flagged comment."? How can I try to return a comment?

Comment: Is there any need for the comment _after_ it has been removed? If not, then don't bother.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy the post is incorrect. It is BAD to delete both comments (of mine and Gwag) that are pointing to the errors in it.

Comment: @Gangnus, then just downvote the answer.

Comment: @Vicky downvoting the answer without commenting? I almost never do it. Mostly I comment the post and only if the author won't edit the error, I downvote it.

Comment: @Gangnus, only if the comment got upvotes, it could be retained, even if it's been flagged.

Comment: The only genuinely informative comment on that answer is the first one, which I have undeleted.  As to downvoting, it's perfectly acceptable to downvote with or without explanation, based on the content of the answer at the time you encounter it.

Comment: @Robert But I'm not sure unexplained downvotes are something we want to _encourage_... They happen, and we're used to them, but I appreciate it when people explain.

Comment: @Emracool: You'll change your mind the first time you get dragged into a protracted argument over your downvote explanation.

Comment: @Robert I'm not new here, you know...

Comment: So you know exactly what I'm talking about, then.

Comment: @Robert Yeah, users who get into heated arguments over their downvote choices are frustrating, I understand. I still think that in the long run, if people figure out how not to enter heated arguments and just move on, explanation of downvotes is helpful. It's a debatable point, though.